# Avoid D3js circles overlap within multiple clusters and increasing node radius in D3 v5

Tags: d3.js

I have a D3 visualization with multiple clusters and I use a gravity function to get all the circles to the center of the focus. However, with this, the circles are overlapping.

I tried this block https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3231298 by converting it into V5 but I cant get it to work.

I am using a negative charge to repel the nodes, obviously when I call the gravity function in tick, it gets the codes to the center of cluster focus

```
force = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
            .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody(-100))
            .force('collision', d3.forceCollide().radius(function (d) {
                return 1.1*d.radius;
            }))
            .on('tick', tick);
        force.alpha(0.01);
        force.alphaDecay = 0.1;
        force.alphaTarget(.001);


        force.force('x', d3.forceX().x(function (d) {
            return foci[d.choice].x;
        }))


        force.force('y', d3.forceY().y(function (d) {
            return foci[d.choice].y;
        }))

        console.log(JSON.stringify(foci));

        // Draw circle for each node.
        circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
            .data(nodes)
            .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("id", function (d) {
                return d.id;
            })
            .attr("class", "node")
            .style("stroke", "black");
            ;


        // For smoother initial transition to settling spots.
        // Need to research more on this
        circle.transition()
            .duration(100)
            .delay(function (d, i) {
                return i * 5;
            })
            .attrTween("r", function (d) {
                var i = d3.interpolate(0, d.radius);
                return function (t) {
                    return d.radius = i(t);
                };
            });
function tick(e) {
        circle
            .each(collide(0.5))
            .each(gravity(.051 * .8))
            .style("fill", function (d) {
                //category is either 0 or 1
                //so it's either 0+the choice or 6+the choice
                //d.choice is between 0 and 5
                multiplier = d.category

                return colors[foci_count * multiplier + d.choice];
            })
            .attr("cx", function (d) {
                return d.x;
            })
            .attr("cy", function (d) {
                return d.y;
            })
            .attr("r", function(d) {
                return d.radius;
            })

            ;
    }

function collide(alpha) {
            var quadtree = d3.quadtree().addAll(nodes);

            return function (d) {
                // var r = d.radius + maxNodeRadius + Math.max(padding, clusterPadding),
                var r = d.radius + 10,
                    nx1 = d.x - r,
                    nx2 = d.x + r,
                    ny1 = d.y - r,
                    ny2 = d.y + r;



                 quadtree.visit(function (quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
                    console.log("visit")
                    if (quad.point && (quad.point !== d)) {
                        var x = d.x - quad.point.x,
                            y = d.y - quad.point.y,
                            l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),

                            r = d.radius + quad.point.radius + 10;

                        console.log(d.cluster);

                        if (l < r) {
                            l = (l - r) / l * alpha;
                            d.x -= x *= l;
                            d.y -= y *= l;
                            quad.point.x += x;
                            quad.point.y += y;
                        }
                    }
                    return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
                });
            };
        }


      // Move nodes toward cluster focus.
     function gravity(alpha) {
        return function (d) {
            d.y += (foci[d.choice].y - d.y) * alpha;
            d.x += (foci[d.choice].x - d.x) * alpha;
        };
     }
```

Comment: why do you have a collision force and you call collision in the tick? d3v5 has a gravity force. play with the strengths of the forces, if gravity is stronger than collide you get overlap

Comment: The reason I call collision in tick is that the tick function has will update the radius of the node. And I dont want the circles to overlap during that time.

Comment: then reinitialize the collide force with the updated nodes

Comment: Ah yes, I was going down the rabbit hole of trying to get it work with the existing examples(that use d3 v3) using quadtree. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

As @rioV8 has mentioned, all I needed to do was re-initialize the collide force with the updated nodes. So I updated my tick function to the following

```
 function tick(e) {
        circle

            .each(gravity(.051 * .8))
            .style("fill", function (d) {
                //category is either 0 or 1
                //so it's either 0+the choice or 6+the choice
                //d.choice is between 0 and 5
                multiplier = d.category

                return colors[foci_count * multiplier + d.choice];
            })
            .attr("cx", function (d) {
                return d.x;
            })
            .attr("cy", function (d) {
                return d.y;
            })
            .attr("r", function(d) {
                return d.radius;
            });


            force.force('collision', d3.forceCollide().radius(function (d) {
                return 1.3 * d.radius;
            }));
    }
```

Comment: why still call `each` for `collide` and `gravity`?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove the call to collide for each. I would need the gravity so that I can enforce the nodes to focus towards the center of the cluster